# convertir proyecto react a react native

Tags: django, reactjs, react-native

puedo poner una pagina web creada con [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) convertirla [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native)?, y si es posible como, será que puedo reutilizar el mismo servidor de la pagina web, con la app de react-native para que se pueda acceder al mismo usuario, las funciones y privilegios de el mismo usuario tanto en la web como en la app.

es posible yo usar Django como back en react y react-native, el mismo servidor para los dos

Comment: Creo que además de ser una pregunta muy amplia, la cual seguramente cerrarán, supongo que no podrás hacer esa conversión tan fácilmente, ya que reac-native a pesar de usar react, está muy orientada a mobile y no a web. Sin embargo, siempre será posible usar un servidor de backend como Django, solo debes hacer una API donde tomar los datos que necesites

Comment: Osea mi pregunta en si es si puedo usar el mismo servidor back que uso en la pagina web poder usarlo en la App de react native

Comment: daniel y user58113 son la misma persona?

Comment: si, solo que no se porque se me puso con user el comentario

Comment: Tienes q aprender react native y cambiar todo, react native es mas sencillo, son menos equiquetas que existen.

Answer (score 7):

Sí puedes utilizar el mismo backend para las dos aplicaciones. Los dos deberían utilizar el mismo proceso para hacer login/signup.

Tus dos aplicaciones pueden traer información de `https://tuapi.com/`

Si lo que quieres es compartir código entre la app native y la web puedes echarle un ojo a https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

También puedes crear un monorepo para tener en el mismo sitio el proyecto en React Native, React Web y la lógica del negocio utilizando Redux/MobX o lo que te funcione mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que la mayoría de componentes de React Native (¿o quizá todos?) son diferentes a los de React.

Por ejemplo, en React Native no se utilizan elementos html, como `<div>` o `<ul>` o `<p>`, y en cambio sí se usan componentes específicos para móvil, como `<View>` o `<Text>`.

Por tanto, un código fuente en React tendría que modificarse para usar los componentes de React Native. Obviamente, no se trata de meros cambios de nombre, sino que la lógica y la forma de utilizarlos cambia también.

Answer (score 0):

Son dos frameworks orientados a tecnologías distintas, una a la web y otro al mobile.

Puedes replantear la arquitectura de tu aplicación orientándola a microservicios, de esa forma podrás enfocar toda tu lógica de negocio en el backend y suministrar al front toda la información necesaria a través de APIS.

O como dice el compañero Alejandro Nanez puedes utilizar el marco de react-native-web, que te proporciona todo un entorno para configurar una sola aplicación, ya dependera de tu necesidad, tiempo y esfuerzo.

https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web